# In dart,How to remove element in the NestedList

Tags: flutter, dart

Element not removed from the List. pls tell me how could i remove the element in the list

```
    void main() {
     List data=[['apple',1],['banana',5]];
       data.remove(['apple',1]);
       print(data);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining dynamic objects like ['apple', 1]. Declare a class for it, and tell the program how those instances should be compared such as

```
class Fruit  {
final String name;
final int index;

Fruit(this.index, this.name);

@override
int get hashCode => name.hashCode + index.hashCode * 7;
}
```

and then use it like;

```
void main() {
     List data=[Fruit('apple', 1), Fruit('banana', 5),];
       data.remove(['apple',1]);
       print(data);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very recommended to use `List<dynamic>` everywhere in dart. [Tolga Kartal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68516297/in-dart-how-to-remove-element-in-the-nestedlist#answer-68516435) gives a better practice.

Bur for your case, if you do not want to refactor your code, you can first find where `['apple', 1]` is and then delete it from `data`.

```
void main() {
  List data=[['apple',1],['banana',5]];

  dynamic targetElement = data.firstWhere(
    (element) => element[0]=='apple' && element[1]==1,
    orElse: () => null);

  if (targetElement != null) 
    data.remove(targetElement);

  print(data);
}
```

The reason why you can't directly use `data.remove(['apple', 1])` is that every time you use `['apple', 1]`, what you're actually doing is declaring a new `List` object. Although both `['apple', 1]` have exactly same elements, their addresses in memory are different. To be more specific, they have different hash codes.

```
void main() {
  List<dynamic> itemA = ['apple', 1];
  List<dynamic> itemB = ['apple', 1];
  print('hashcode of itemA and itemB');
  print('itemA: ${itemA.hashCode}, itemB: ${itemB.hashCode}');
  // <<< itemA: 397807318, itemB: 278500865

  print('verify if they have same elements inside');
  print('itemA[0] == itemB[0]:${itemA[0] == itemB[0]}, itemA[1] == itemB[1]:${itemA[1] == itemB[1]}');
  // <<< itemA[0] == itemB[0]:true, itemA[1] == itemB[1]:true

  print('check if itemA and itemB are same');
  print('itemA == itemB: ${itemA == itemB}');
  // <<< itemA == itemB: false
  
  print('A case to show why they are different');
  itemA.add('Hello');
  itemB.add('World');
  print('itemA: $itemA');
  // <<< itemA: [apple, 1, Hello]
  print('itemB: $itemB');
  // <<< itemB: [apple, 1, World]
}
```

Hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace ['apple',1] to index,  In this case 0

```
void main() {
 List data=[['apple',1],['banana',5]];
   data.remove(0);
   print(data);
 }
```

Hope it work